# Unable to remotely schedule tasks from the command line

Tags: command-line, remote-access, windows-task-scheduler, credentials

I'm on a Windows 7 machine, attempting to use the command line to schedule a task on another Windows 7 machine in my company's network. I have administrative-level credentials for both computers. With help from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357.aspx I have created this line to run on the command prompt:

```
schtasks /Create /S machinename /U username /P password /SC ONCE /TN Test1 /TR C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe /ST 16:30
```

Whenever I launch that, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: User credentials are not allowed on the local machine.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct syntax:

```
schtasks /Create /S machinename /RU domain\username /RP password /SC ONCE /TN Test1 /TR C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe /ST 16:30
```

Note the **/RU** and the **/RP** where /U and /P used to be. We are using RU for "Run as User".
Also note that **we must specify the domain** that we are logging onto.

This was answered by Aseem Kishore and Brian Gibson here: 
http://thebackroomtech.com/2009/04/06/windows-2008-schtasks-error-user-credentials-are-not-allowed-on-the-local-machine/ via http://brianagibson.blogspot.com/2008/08/hmc-45-domaincachetask-scheduled-task.html

Comment: Doesn't RU change the credentials under which the task itself is run and not  the credentials under which the schtasks command is run?